# Where should i set 'requires_grad', or is this not the problem?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, pytorch-lightning

I'm building an multi-choice QA model based on BERT variant with classification head, which pool tokens locally(by answers).
The inference works well but there are some errors for running training loop.

I used pre-trained model DeBERTa,

```
deberta = 'microsoft/deberta-v2-xxlarge'
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(deberta)
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'additional_special_tokens' : ['[QA]', '[ANS]']})
plm = AutoModel.from_pretrained(deberta)
plm.to('cuda')
```

And the model class is :

```
class BertWithHead(DebertaPreTrainedModel, pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, tokenizer, model, learning_rate=2e-5):
        super(BertWithHead, self).__init__(model.config)
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.special_tokens_ids =  tokenizer.additional_special_tokens_ids
        self.bert = model
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
    
        self.mlp = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(in_features=self.bert.config.hidden_size, out_features=256),
                                 nn.SiLU(inplace=True),
                                 nn.Linear(in_features=256, out_features=1),)
        self.CELoss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        

    def sequence_spliter(self, spliter, split_data) :
        splited_batch=[]
        for s, data in zip(spliter, split_data):
            sliced_data=[]
            tmp=0
            split_indices = (s == True).nonzero(as_tuple=False).squeeze().to('cuda')
            for j in range(len(split_indices)):
                sliced_data.append(data[tmp:split_indices[j]])
                tmp=split_indices[j]+1
            sliced_data.append(data[tmp:-1])
            splited_batch.append(sliced_data)
        return splited_batch


        def scorer(self, token_embeddings):
        answers_x = [torch.stack([torch.mean(i, 0) for i in x[1:]]) for x in token_embeddings]
        answers_x = torch.stack(answers_x)
        return torch.stack([self.mlp(i) for i in answers_x]).squeeze(-1)

    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask):
        spliter = input_ids == self.special_tokens_ids[0]
        spliter += input_ids == self.special_tokens_ids[1]
    
        outputs = self.bert(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
        bert_output = outputs.last_hidden_state
        splited_batch = self.sequence_spliter(spliter, bert_output)
        return self.scorer(splited_batch)


    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = AdamW(self.parameters(), lr=self.learning_rate)
        return optimizer

    def loss_fn(self, logits, labels):
        loss = self.CELoss(logits, labels)
        return torch.tensor(loss, dtype=torch.float32, device='cuda')

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        batch_tokenized = tokenizer(batch['text'], return_tensors='pt', padding=True).to('cuda')
        input_ids = batch_tokenized['input_ids'].to('cuda')
        attention_mask = batch_tokenized['attention_mask'].to('cuda')
    
        labels = torch.tensor(batch['answer'], device='cuda')
        logits = self.forward(input_ids, attention_mask).float()#.requires_grad_(True)
        loss = self.loss_fn(logits, labels)#.requires_grad_(True)
        self.log('train_loss', loss)
        return loss

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        batch_tokenized = tokenizer(batch['text'], return_tensors='pt', padding=True)
        input_ids = batch_tokenized['input_ids'].to('cuda')
        attention_mask = batch_tokenized['attention_mask'].to('cuda')

        labels = torch.tensor(batch['answer'], device='cuda')
        logits = self.forward(input_ids, attention_mask).float()#.requires_grad_(True)
        loss = self.loss_fn(logits, labels)#.requires_grad_(True)
        self.log('val_loss', loss)
        return loss
```

The error cames from training loop:

```
model = BertWithHead(tokenizer, plm)
model.to('cuda')

batch_size = 8

train_size = int(0.8 * len(data['train']))
val_size = len(data['train']) - train_size
train_dataset, val_dataset = random_split(data['train'], [train_size, val_size])

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size)

trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=3, accelerator="auto")
trainer.fit(model, train_dataloaders=train_loader, val_dataloaders=val_loader)
```

And the error output is here:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[135], line 16
     13 val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size)
     15 trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=3, accelerator="auto")
---> 16 trainer.fit(model, train_dataloaders=train_loader, val_dataloaders=val_loader)

                ... No mentions of my code ...

File ~/anaconda3/envs/sciqa/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py:200, in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables, inputs)
    195     retain_graph = create_graph
    197 # The reason we repeat same the comment below is that
    198 # some Python versions print out the first line of a multi-line function
    199 # calls in the traceback and some print out the last line
--> 200 Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
    201     tensors, grad_tensors_, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs,
    202     allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)

RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

I want to know what exactly means `element 0 of tensors` and want to know how to solve this problem.
I tried using options `requires_grad=True` every params and features.
Probably the `sequence_spliter()` or `scorer()` could cause the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrapping the loss with `torch.tensor`, which detaches the loss from the computation graph, making it not require gradients. As a result, when you call backward() during training, it raises the "element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn" error.

Return the loss tensor without wrapping it with `torch.tensor`.

Don't know about `scorer()` or `sequence_spliter()` functions